# Why does the output of logistic regression using GLM is different from using the formula 1/(1+exp(-y)) with y=b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + ... + bn?*xn

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, least-squares

When I use glm with family=binomial I get different results than if I use the direct formula, I have looked for an explanation for this and I can't find anything. I hope you can help me!

```
input <- mtcars[,c("am","cyl","hp","wt")]
lm_reg<-lm(formula = am ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = input)
res_lm<-predict(lm_reg, input, type = "response")
res_lm_logis<-1/(1+exp(-res_lm)) #logistic regression using 1/(1+exp(-y))

logistic_reg<-glm(formula = am ~ cyl + hp + wt, data = input, family = binomial)
res_glm_bin<-predict(logistic_reg, input, type="response") #logistic regression usign glm,      family= binomial

output<-as.data.frame(cbind(res_lm_logis,res_glm_bin)) #outputs of both ways, here you can see the differences of the two methods
```

I would like to understand why there are differences in the results of this two methods if in theory both are the same

Comment: (And, in theme with that, if you write these out as actual equations not as code, *including the error term*, I think the difference will be much clearer)

Answer (score 1):

`lm` implements OLS, which estimates the coefficient vector $\beta$ that minimizes the square error:

$$
\mathcal L_\text{ols} = \left\|X\beta - y \right\|^2
$$

whereas the `glm` function with `family=binomial` estimates a logistic regression model. This model minimizes the binomial cross-entropy loss:

$$
\mathcal L_\text{binomial} = \sum_i -y_i\log\left(\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x_i\beta)}\right)-(1-y_i)\log\left(1-\frac{1}{1 + \exp(-x_i\beta)}\right)
$$

There is no reason that the resulting $\beta$ values should be the same in general.